# ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature"

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ejs

I am getting this in error in node js while running a server. The error is as follows

> "(node:17160) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an
> experimental feature". This feature could change at any time"?

Full details can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZGwS.png)

Any idea how to solve this? I am getting it in the terminal while running the nomemon server.js. My codes are as follows:

Here is mine:

Server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId)
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
  })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

script.js

```
const socket = io('/')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host:'/',
    port:'3002'
})
myPeer.on('open', id => {
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, 10)

socket.on('User-connected', userId => {
    console.log('User-connected:' + userId)
})
```

Room.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Just Not a Document</title>
    <script>
        const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
      </script>
      <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>

      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
      <script src="script.js" defer></script>
      <style>
        #video-grid {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
          grid-auto-rows: 300px;
        }
        
        video {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          object-fit: cover;
        }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not an error. It is just a warning indicating that you are using functionality that the developers may remove in future updates. The decision is based on their future experiments. You must trace back to see where the source of the warning is and what stable alternatives you have for that specific part.

Comment: You're not using conditional exports anywhere in your code. Must a package that you're using. Tried using all the ones that you imported with no issue. Try updating packages to the latest version.